# JavaScript onload and DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, onload-event

I have this example document:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.body.onload = myFunc();

            function myFunc() {
                element = document.getElementById('myDiv');
                element.innerHTML = 'Hello!';
            }
        </script>
        <div id="myDiv"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why 'element' is null if `myFunc` is a callback of `document.body.onload`?

If, instead, the script is inserted after the div, it works:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="myDiv"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.body.onload = myFunc();

            function myFunc() {
                element = document.getElementById('myDiv');
                element.innerHTML = 'Hello!';
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My question is: if I use the `onload` event within the handler function, should I have the entire DOM, or not? Why should I not?

Comment: Although ThiefMaster has pointed out the bug in your code, this might be helpful for you - accessing `document.body` before `DOMContentLoaded` might give you errors. So, be aware of that too :) Even jquery checks for existence of `document` object to confirm that dom is ready for scripts to access. `var body = document || document.body || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]` might be helpful if you are to do great stuff in future ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling the function immediately (and assign its return value).

Assign the function instead and it will work:

```
document.body.onload = myFunc;
```

You should also use `var element` in your function to avoid creating a global variable.

---

Or if you want to confuse people:

```
document.body.onload = myFunc();
function myFunc() {
    return function() {
        var element = document.getElementById('myDiv');
        element.innerHTML = 'Hello!';
    };
}
```

But let's **not** do that. It makes no sense here. ;)

Comment: You opened my eyes! LOL
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
document.body.onload = myFunc;
```

Or

```
document.body.onload = function() {
    myFunc();
};
```